# Flask-SQLAlchemy query.get() throws exception when querying for nonexistent key

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask app that needs to manage user logins and sessions.  I have run into an unusual error when attempting to validate a user's session.  I use Flask sessions to store the user's current sessionId, then the application uses the sessionId to look up the current session from a sessions table in the database.

This is the code generating the error:

```
session_id = flask.session.get("session_id", "")
session = models.Session.Session.query.get(session_id)
```

This is the error I get from SQLAlchemy:

```
File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/routes.py", line 24, in index
    return controllers.index.indexController()
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/controllers/index.py", line 17, in indexController
    session = models.Session.Session.query.get(session_id)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 831, in get
    return self._get_impl(ident, loading.load_on_ident)
  File "/home/gunicorn/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAMEenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 842, in _get_impl
    if len(ident) != len(mapper.primary_key):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

It appears that when `query.get()` is run for an index that does not exist in the table, this error is thrown, though the API docs for Flask-SQLAlchemy state that it should return `None` in this case.

For reference, here is the code for my Session model:

```
class Session(db.Model):
     sessionId = db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
     userId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.userId'), nullable=False)
     createdOn = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())
```

**EDIT FOR COMPLETENESS:**
My directory structure is linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Llz.png). run.py is the file where the Flask() object is created and run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error happens when you pass `None` as parameter of `get()` method. You can verify if session_id variable is not None before querying

```
if session_id is not None:
    session = models.Session.Session.query.get(session_id)
else:
    # do something
```

or you can use the `filter_by()` method in conjunction with `first()` method:

```
session = models.Session.Session.query.filter_by(sessionId=session_id).first()
```

it will return None if not was found.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is correct the way I have it. My directory structure has models as a package with the file Session.py in it, and there is a class Session defined within Session.py.

Comment: Can you give more details about the implementation? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No problem! I just edited in an image of the directory structure of the project.

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstanding your problem. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to use the second solution.